# how to calculate the difference(s) between repeated measures in R

Tags: r, duplicates, difference

df as follows:

```
ID     cat1
A0001   358
A0001   279
A0008   422
A0008   433
A0049   324
A0049   358
A0049   432
```

I wanted to calculate the difference in value in cat1 between the repeated measures (by unique ID).

The expected output should look like:

```
 ID    cat1 cat1_diff
A0001   358   NA
A0001   279   -79
A0008   422   NA
A0008   433   11
A0049   324   NA
A0049   358   26
A0049   432   74
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Should be straightforward - to clarify, can you show an expected outcome for these 4 cases?

Comment: How do you want to aggregate the diff between two columns, e.g. `Cat2` and `Cat3`, for a group of given `ID` ?

Comment: I would like to make a new column for each cat. i.e. Cat2_diff   with the result listed in the same row of the latter entry

Comment: You could just do `aggregate(.~ID, df, diff)`

Comment: Would that work for triplicate repeated measures? Some entries I have contain triplicates or quads.

Comment: @sleepyjoe - no, not really.

Comment: So the Aggregate and diff function would only work for sum diff. But I actually wanted to record each individual difference between repeated measures.

Comment: If you have triplicates or quads you should provide an example of these in your example data and show your *exact* desired output per the provided data set.

Comment: @sleepyjoe David is *right*. You should have modified your `data.frame` to cover all the cases you want.

Comment: Thanks David, psyco and thelatemail. I have edited my df to make it clear. I would really appreciate your help on this.